# Formatting date and time with iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How do I format date and time using iPhone SDK?

For example, how would I extract the date from  `9/4/2024 12:00:00 AM` to NSDate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can format your string using **dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a**

**example as below:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"12/12/2012 12:12:12 AM"]);
```

Comment: I corrected your answer to use 'mm' (minutes) instead of 'MM' (months), and 'ss' (seconds) instead of 'SS' (sub-seconds) in the time part of the formatter string.

Answer (score 48):

some more option

Now you want all the string formats that can be used with NSDateFormatter. Here is that

---

a: AM/PM

A: 0~86399999 (Millisecond of Day)

c/cc: 1~7 (Day of Week)

ccc: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat

cccc: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday

d: 1~31 (0 padded Day of Month)

D: 1~366 (0 padded Day of Year)

e: 1~7 (0 padded Day of Week)

E~EEE: Sun/Mon/Tue/Wed/Thu/Fri/Sat

EEEE: Sunday/Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday/Saturday

F: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, first day of week = Monday)

g: Julian Day Number (number of days since 4713 BC January 1)

G~GGG: BC/AD (Era Designator Abbreviated)

GGGG: Before Christ/Anno Domini

h: 1~12 (0 padded Hour (12hr))

H: 0~23 (0 padded Hour (24hr))

k: 1~24 (0 padded Hour (24hr)

K: 0~11 (0 padded Hour (12hr))

L/LL: 1~12 (0 padded Month)

LLL: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

LLLL: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December

m: 0~59 (0 padded Minute)

M/MM: 1~12 (0 padded Month)

MMM: Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec

MMMM: January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/December

q/qq: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)

qqq: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

qqqq: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter

Q/QQ: 1~4 (0 padded Quarter)

QQQ: Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

QQQQ: 1st quarter/2nd quarter/3rd quarter/4th quarter

s: 0~59 (0 padded Second)

S: (rounded Sub-Second)

u: (0 padded Year)

v~vvv: (General GMT Timezone Abbreviation)

vvvv: (General GMT Timezone Name)

w: 1~53 (0 padded Week of Year, 1st day of week = Sunday, NB: 1st week of year starts from the last Sunday of last year)

W: 1~5 (0 padded Week of Month, 1st day of week = Sunday)

y/yyyy: (Full Year)

yy/yyy: (2 Digits Year)

Y/YYYY: (Full Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)

YY/YYY: (2 Digits Year, starting from the Sunday of the 1st week of year)

z~zzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Abbreviation)

zzzz: (Specific GMT Timezone Name)

Z: +0000 (RFC 822 Timezone)

Comment: But, When I using  this I getting 5 hours less than the exact time.

Comment: Here is the complete list: 

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for dateformat OR Check This code

[Click this link here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html)

```
NSString *Datee=@"1/06/2013 8:11:12 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:Datee];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method, just pass your date to it :

```
-(NSString *)getDateFromString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",string];

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"your current date format"];
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"your desired format"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];

    NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);
    return stringFromDate;
}
```