# date formatter issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i am using the following piece of code to convert string to date but the time format is not coming correctly when i log the date

```
NSDateFormatter *formate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"];
    [formate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSString *strConcat = @"03/06/2013  2:59 PM";
    NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:strConcat];
    NSLog(@"Output :%@",date);
```

**Output** :`2013-03-06 12:59:00 +0000`

can any one please where i am doing wrong in converting it into date .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086492/formatting-date-and-time-with-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Your error is by `HH` in dateFormat you need to use `hh`

// hh  gives 14:59

// HH  gives 12:59

```
NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"]; 
[formate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSString *strConcat = @"03/06/2013  2:59 PM";
NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:strConcat];
NSLog(@"Output :%@",date);
```

Comment: This is not a timezone issue. It is due to the difference between `HH` (24-hour) and `hh` (12-hour) format.

Comment: @MartinR: 2:59 PM will be 14:59 isn't it? Here hh give 14:59 while HH 12:59

Comment: If you use `hh:mm a` as date format then `2:29 PM` is correctly parsed to `14:59`. The combination `HH` for 24-hour format plus AM/PM probably does not work (it does not make much sense anyway). -  The timezone is explicitly set to GMT, so it cannot be a timezone problem