# IOS - Date formatting from string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to format a date to display in a uitableview custom cell

The data is passed into the app from a CMS - it is provided as a string in the following format and stored in a date type variable-

```
2014-04-15 10:10:45 +0000
```

Our app will initially be UK based - so I need to convert the format into DD/MM/YYYY format.

I tried the following code to parse my date  (dateadded which is of type date).

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
cellRecP.artDate.text = [formatter stringFromDate:resItem.dateadded];
```

but this just returns null - i guess the date format provided above is not anything that stringfromdate understands - is there any other way to format date?

Comment: You'll need to customize an NSDateFormatter and add the above as formatting string... which is covered all rather well in the documentation and on SO...

Comment: People down-voting the answer should always explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an 'NSDateFormatter'

```
NSDateFormatter* newFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
```

with this format to parse the string

```
[newFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"];
NSDate* aDate = [newFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

and you should get a valid 'NSDate' object

Answer (score 1):

Try This and also Checkout this [All Formate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086492/formatting-date-and-time-with-iphone-sdk) It is really good and helpful.

```
NSString *yourString = @"2014-04-15 10:10:45 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];//Set Your Timezone
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];//You have to set this formate.
NSDate *dd = [df dateFromString:yourString];//This will convert into date;
//Now you can set your formate.
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *str = [df stringFromDate:dd];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a proper unicode parse string. NSDateFormatter by default automatically checks the device locale setting the correct output.
This is an example from some code of mine:

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateWriter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateWriter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'ZZZ";
        dateWriter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
        dateWriter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
```

Pay attention that date formatters are pretty expensive to create.