# Get desired date object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a string:

```
NSString* string=@"2014-10-02 18:15:00 +0000";
```

How can I get date object with this string?

I tried:

```
  NSString* string=@"2014-10-02 18:15:00 +0000";
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z"];
  NSDate *mydate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
  NSLog(@"mydate = %@",mydate);
```

`mydate` logs null value. I was expecting to log 2014-10-02 18:15:00 +0000.

All I want is to have date object which can be compared to another date object that displays 2014-10-02 18:15:00 +0000 when logged.

Comment: use `HH`in place of `hh`. because you are getting 24hr date format. `hh` mean 12hr format and `HH` mean 24hr format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You string is in 24 hour format but 'hh' is for 12 hour format. and 'HH' is for 24 hour format. Thats why it was returning null. Try this:

```
  NSString* string=@"2014-10-02 18:15:00 +0000";
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
  NSDate *mydate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
  NSLog(@"mydate = %@",mydate);
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

because you are using `hh` which gives 12hr formate date. but you are getting 24hr formate so you have to use `HH` which gives 24hr format. For more Details about date formate check Vanya's answer .Here is very good Explaination about almost all format.([Formatting date and time with iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086492/formatting-date-and-time-with-iphone-sdk))

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use "z" instead "Z" for zone

```
NSString* string=@"2014-10-02 18:15:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
NSDate *mydate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"mydate = %@",mydate);
```