# iOS Date Formatter Returns Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have searched the internet for a solution but have not been able to solve my problem.

I have a date that I am formatting but it always returns null.

```
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss.ZZZZ"];
    NSString *dueDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2014-07-11T15:21:42.207+0200"];
    NSDate *dateFromApi = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dueDateString];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
    NSString *finalDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromApi];
    NSLog(@"dueDateString %@", dueDateString);
    NSLog(@"dateFromApi %@", dateFromApi);
    NSLog(@"finalDateString%@", finalDateString);
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong but the format above seems to work if I use this format 0001-01-03T00:00:00.000+0200 I get an output of 0001/01/02. As soon as it changes like this 2014-07-11T15:21:42.207+0200 it does not work and always returns null?

Comment: Refer this link to set dateformat: http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/ . It will help you.

Comment: try `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzzZ` format. i got `2014-07-11 15:21:41 +0000` . for more details about date formating please check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086492/formatting-date-and-time-with-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
NSString *dueDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2014-07-11T15:21:42.207+02:00"];
NSDate *dateFromApi = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dueDateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
NSString *finalDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromApi];
NSLog(@"dueDateString %@", dueDateString);
NSLog(@"dateFromApi %@", dateFromApi);
NSLog(@"finalDateString%@", finalDateString);
```