# NSDateFormatter always returning nil

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code:

```
var sdArr = sd.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(sdArr[0])
```

The value of `sdArr[0]` is `"2015-10-01T14:30:00"`

Why is the value of date is nil? This was working fine 2 days ago and I didn't touch my code. Now suddenly out of the blue value of date is nil.
I've tried putting the date string in place of `sdArr[0]` but it still not working

Comment: add dateformat `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: @crysis Just to let you know. Looks like your date it is an ISO8601 format. It might be UTC time and you are treating it as localtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use date formatter as

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

You are using `hh` which is for 12 hour format, `HH` is for 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

add dateformat `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` because you are getting hour in 24 hour format not 12 hour format so you have to use `HH`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" //HH
```

Please refer [Formatting date and time with iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086492/formatting-date-and-time-with-iphone-sdk) (Vanya's answer) to know more regarding date formaters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `NSDateFormatter`

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```