# Why I can't convert string to date in Swift?

Tags: swift, datetime, swift3, nsdateformatter

I have this simple code:

```
let string = "2017-02-23 15:26:00";
let df = DateFormatter();
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
let result = df.date(from: string);
```

The result is nil. Why?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32599745/1187415, http://stackoverflow.com/a/36647146/1187415, and some more.

Comment: i faced the same issue, the accepted answer below helped me fix the issue. I checked the question marked as duplicate too, but it seems like different one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your date is 24 hour format So it should be `HH` not `hh`, so change your date formate to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

```
let string = "2017-02-23 15:26:00"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let result = df.date(from: string)
```

Comment: OMG. I will never get that. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenLiYong Welcome mate :)

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: @R.Mohan Welcome mate :)

Comment: Thanks Hero!! Worked for me in 5 Sec.

Answer (score 0):

```
let string = "2017-02-23 15:26:00";
let df = DateFormatter();
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
let result = df.date(from: string);
```

Comment: What.........?!